# In Java, what is difference between 1 and 2 statement Integer and int

Tags: java

1>Integer ie = Integer.valueOf("45");//give output 45

2>int ie = Integer.valueof("45");//give same output as 45

// can you tell me difference between 1 and second statement

3>Integer i3 = Integer.valueOf("70");//give output as 70

4>int i3 = Integer.valueOf("70");// also give same output

Answer (score 1):

Its called unBoxing in java which was introduced in JAVA 5 `Integer` is wrapper class which provides `Integer object` to un-boxed into `int` primitive data type. Integer has `static` methods like

```
static Integer valueOf(int i)
static Integer valueOf(String s)
static Integer valueOf(String s, int radix)
```

Similar wrapper classes for other primitive data types

```
byte has Byte
short has Short
int has Integer
long has Long
boolean has Boolean
char has Character
float has Float
double has Double
```

Answer (score 0):

The first query gives you an `Object`of type `Integer`.

The second query gives you a primitive type int. That will be the same as `Integer.valueof("45").intValue()`;